# UI grid 3.0 with angular bootstrap accordion

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap, accordion, angular-ui-grid

Hi Guys I'm working with UI grid and want to extend a each row with angular bootstrap accordion but nothing working.
Does anybody have an Idea how to do that?

`Link:`
http://plnkr.co/edit/Hc6y66e4oE35XhOQZN4t?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out how to add accordion to subgrid
I was using Expandable grid module [enter link description here](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/216_expandable_grid)

Then Just deleted the template for subgrid and created my own.
You can see the example at

```
Hi Guys,
```

I find out how to add accordion to subgrid
I was using Expandable grid module [enter link description here](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/216_expandable_grid)

Then Just deleted the template for subgrid and created my own.
You can see the example at [enter link description here](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hc6y66e4oE35XhOQZN4t?p=preview)